# Finding Maximum and Minimum values in c++ by user input

Tags: c++, max, minimum

i want to know how can i find the maximum and minimum value in c++ by user input value and and user also put the limit for  for loop , for example :

Write a c++ program that initially takes an integer value from the user as the loop’s limit. It means that the loop will execute the same times as the input from the user. The loop will then take integer values as input from the user until it reaches loop limit. 
You are required to use only one variable which will be used to take input repeatedly from the user inside the loop. It means you are not allowed to use the array or multiple variables for this purpose. After that your program will calculate sum of entered values, their average, minimum and maximum values along with position on which these values were entered.

i wrote but stuck on maximum and minimum.. here is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int value;
int ivalue;
int sum=0;
int average;
int x,y;


cout << "Enter loop limit : "; cin >> value ;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

for( x=0;x<=value-1;x++){
        cout << "Enter "<<x+1<<" value : "; cin >> ivalue;
        sum=sum+ivalue;
}
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<endl;
   cout << "Sum of entered values : " <<sum <<endl;
   cout << "Average of entered values : "<< sum/value<<endl;

 }
```

Comment: Compare the input with your current maximum and if it is bigger use it as the new maximum.

Comment: If you had `int maximum` to hold the maximum value, then you could use `maximum = x ? std::max(maximum, ivalue) : ivalue;` in your `for` loop. Note the use of the *ternary conditional*. Note that `maximum` will remain uninitialised if `value` is zero: don't read it back in that instance.

Comment: *It means you are not allowed to use the array or multiple variables for this purpose.* -- which purpose? Is it allowed to have two variables for minimum and maximum like the solution posted below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define the maximum as the lowest possible value:

```
int maximum = -INFINITY;
```

then at each value compare and set new maximum if necessary:

```
if (ivalue > maximum)
    maxumum = ivalue;
```

for minimum you would use the same kind of logic...

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that any value entered will be a larger value than what you initialize "max" to, you need to initialize it to the smallest possible integer value.

```
int max = INT_MIN;
```

You will need to do the opposite for the minimum, for the same reasons.

```
int min = INT_MAX;
```

You also need to keep track of the iteration of the loop in order to find the position when the maximum and minimum were entered.

```
int count = 1;
```

Through each iteration of your loop, you will increment your count variable.

```
count++;
```

Now you will need two variables to track the position of your maximum and minimum.

```
int maxPos = 1;
int minPos = 1;
```

We can initialize the positions to one as we know that at least the first user-entered value will be our new maximum and minimum.

Then, inside your for loop, you will need to test if the value entered by the user is greater than the current maximum, and if it is, to set that value as the new maximum and update the position.

```
if (ivalue > max) {
    max = ivalue;
    maxPos = count;
}
```

You will also need to test the minimum and assign it if the user-entered value is smaller than the current minimum as well as update the position.

```
if (ivalue < min) {
    min = ivalue;
    minPos = count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input;
int max = 0;
int min = 0;

cout << "Enter number: ";
while (input != -1)
{
    cin >> input;
    if(input != -1)
    {
        if(input > max)
        {
            max = input;
        }

        if(input < min)
        {
            min = input;
        }
    }
}
cout <<"Max: " << max << " Min " << min << endl;
```

}

Comment: You should add some explanation of what your code does.